# Why did the Geometers light up the Inviolates?

Tags: anathem

They lit up the 3 Inviolates with laser beams. And that triggered the Convox.  But do we know *why* the Geometers did it?  Why did they want Arbre to know that they knew where the nuclear waste <s>dumps</s> repositories were? At that time? (I don't see how they could have predicted - or desired! - that that would trigger the Convox.)